# Can you generate and apply patches to a docker container offline?

Tags: diff, patch, docker

We're looking into replacing our update system with docker, but we have a unique constraint where all upgrades need to happen offline. The use case is very similar to how you would update router firmware or something from a LAN not connected to the internet.

Currently our users download a patch file, which they then upload to the web interface of our system over a private LAN. Our system applies the patch. It is all implemented with the `diff` and `patch` commands. We do the diffing because our codebase is pretty giant but relatively few files change from version to version.

We think switching to docker can help us tremendously for our development, but for production  and our update system we need to make sure we can do offline, diff-based updates.

My question boils down to this: are there docker analogs to the `diff` and `patch` commands that can be used to update a container offline?

I know docker has commands like `docker diff`, but as per the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#diff) it just shows a list of files that have been added, removed or changed from a container. `docker save` and `docker export` look like they come close though, but they provide full images whereas I'm after a diff. Similarly there seems to be no way as far as I can tell to use `docker load` to load a diff.

Thanks!

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should use private registry for this. Docker image can contain many layers so your update will be just small layer users need to download. Also updating image on local system doesn't affect running containers, so your users will just download new layers on update and then restart running containers from new image. This will be almost same as patch system. So in short from user side it will look like this:

1. docker pull new layers from your private registry instance (need to be online)
2. docker stop old container (offline)
3. docker run new container from updated image

All config files should be stored outside image for example in a docker volume.